# Exciting the Plasma Wake Field in Other Ways

Tags: plasma-physics, accelerator-physics

Is there any way to excite the wakefield in wakefield accelerators other than lasers and particle beams.

Comment: Think about the name of this mechanism for a second.  The acceleration happens similar (very loosely) to how a fly can get pulled along behind a large truck and stay in the relatively calm "eddy pool" immediately behind it.  It's kind of like drafting off a lead in a race.  The neat thing about wakefield acceleration is that if you use a high energy laser pulse, your wake is nearly c so the particles can get a huge kick.